# How to remove the search box from AVG toolbar?

Tags: toolbar, avg-antivirus

I've downloaded the AVG toolbar. I don't want any search engine box in it, but couldn't figure out how to remove it. Is there a way?

Comment: I've decided to uninstall the toolbar. My new question is: http://superuser.com/questions/178296/how-to-uninstall-the-avg-toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't. The only way would be to uninstall it: the search is built in to the toolbar.

There are alternatives to AVG, like avast which is much cleaner. McAfee SiteAdvisor also provides that "search safety ranking (green, yellow and red)" functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to uninstall the toolbar. Problem is I didn't find the AVG Toolbar in the "Uninstall a Program" in the control panel. How do I uninstall the thing (without uninstalling the AVG Anti Virus)?