# How to uninstall the AVG toolbar?

Tags: uninstall, toolbar, avg-antivirus

I can't find AVG Toolbar in the "uninstall a program" in control pannel. How do I uninstall AVG Toolbar without uninstalling the AVG Antivirus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to remove the toolbar alone.

You can hide it though

for most browsers this will work...

From the menubar...
View>>Toolbar>>(uncheck the toolbar)

> Start>>Control Panel>> Internet options>>Programs>>Manage Add-ons
>   Then find it And hit Disable and your good.

Also, there is a tool named Autoruns. You can download it from Microsoft to delete the items started with IE.

Comment: The official way is to remove it using the AVG UI.  Each "component" of AVG, such as LinkSafe, etc. can be disabled indpendently.